# Python - Converting lat/long to geometry

Tags: python, postgresql, geometry

I am using Python to parse a CSV.

Within my CSV I have a longitude and latitude column, and was just wondering if Python offers a way of converting these to geometry like PostGres?

For example, adding an extra column in the CSV containing the geometry in the format of `0101000000804263E5719F20C0508E2C4901E94940` ??

Comment: Reading `WKB` with Python: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119752/reading-postgis-geometry-with-shapely